# Rx js filter method does not return the filter array

Tags: javascript, arrays, rxjs

I want to return filtered observable from Array, but when I am subscribing to this observable it does not return the filtered array, it returns the original array. why?

```
const filterBy = {title: 'javascript'};
const items = [{title: 'javascript'}, {title: 'css'}, {title: 'html'}];


const filtered = Rx.Observable.of(items).filter(i => {
  const filtered = i.filter(item => item.title.indexOf(filterBy.title) !== -1);
  console.log('filtered', filtered); // The array length is one
  return filtered;
})

filtered.subscribe(f => console.log(f) // The array length is three);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this is not how you're supposed to use Observables in RxJS. Filters in RxJS always return another Observables and never directly values the processed.

Operator `filter()` expects you to return boolean `true` or `false` based on whether you want to to include or exclude the item from the processed Observable stream. Since you're passing the entire array as a single value with [`Rx.Observable.of(items)`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-of) it always passes everything or nothing (the returned array is converted into boolean).

So let's use [`Observable.from`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-from) static method to create an Observable from an iterable that'll emit each item in the array as a single value and then just `filter()` to exclude all items that don't match the predicate.

```
const filterBy = {title: 'javascript'};
const items = [{title: 'javascript'}, {title: 'css'}, {title: 'html'}];

const observable = Rx.Observable.from(items).filter(item => {
    return item.title.indexOf(filterBy.title) !== -1;
});

observable.subscribe(f => console.log(f));
```

Comment: But i need to return the array how i can do this?

Comment: @user2999287 You simply can't do it with Observables. I don't know what's your use case but I think you could use just standard `Array.filter()` method or `Array.map()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can return an array with the toArray opereator:

```
const filterBy = {title: 'javascript'};
const items = [{title: 'javascript'}, {title: 'css'}, {title: 'html'}];

const observable = Rx.Observable.from(items).filter(item => {
    return item.title.indexOf(filterBy.title) !== -1;
}).toArray();
```