# Unable to return filtered Observable objects from an array of observable objects

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs

I am trying to return a filtered version of Observable objects from an array of observable objects. I have two services, one that gets the dishes from a server and returns an array of Observable dish, and another service that makes use of that service and gets the dishes that has been marked as favorite, which should also return an array or Observable dish.

At first, I was able to retrieve the expected results by making use of a regular array. please see the working code below:

**Favorite Service:**

```
favorites: Array<any>;

getFavorites(): Observable<Dish[]> {
    return this.dishservice.getDishes().pipe(map(
      dishes => dishes.filter(
          dish => {
            //returns true or false for every dish in dishes
            this.favorites.some(el => el === dish.id)
          }
      )
    ));
}
```

**Dish Service:**

```
getDishes(): Observable<Dish[]> {
    return this.http.get<Dish[]>(baseURL + 'dishes')
      .pipe(catchError(this.processHTTPMsgService.handleError));
}
```

The dish/es that have been marked as favorite does not retain the mark after reloading the page, so I have to make use of the Ionic storage to solve this.

Below is the what I did which ignores the filter and returns all observable dishes:

**Favorite Service:**

```
getFavorites(): Observable<Dish[]> {
    return this.dishservice.getDishes().pipe(map(
      dishes => dishes.filter(
        async dish => {
          await this.storage.get("favorites").then(
            result => {
              //returns true or false for every dish in dishes
              //console.log(result.some(el => el === dish.id));
              return result.some(el => el === dish.id);
            }
          )
        })
    ));
}
```

I am not having any errors, so I am really cornered as to why this is happening. This might be related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40339798/rx-js-filter-method-does-not-return-the-filter-array) but I am not entirely sure.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I managed to think outside of the box and found a solution.

Instead of modifying the Favorite Service, I just had to initialize the favorites: Array; with the storage. Less code and problem solved.

```
storage.get('favorites').then(favorites => {
      if (favorites) {
        console.log(favorites);
        this.favorites = favorites;
      }
      else {
        this.favorites = [];
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
getFavorites(): Observable<Dish[]> {
    return this.dishservice.getDishes().pipe(map(
      dishes => {
          let favorites=await this.storage.get("favorites");
          return  dishes.filter(
          dish => {
        favorites.some(el => el === dish.id)
      })}
    ));
}
```